# Understanding defination of Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition

I was reading the definition of Sobolev space form book Evans.
[image]

From that, I understand the following,

$W^{k,p}(U)$ is space of locally integrable function whose all derivative up to order k are in $L^p$.

So $W^{k,p}(U)\subset L_{loc}^1(U)\cap L^p(U)$.

I thought locally summable condition is considered for defining weak derivative.

Is my understanding of Sobolev space is correct? Please tell me. As I am learning independently with the only help of Mathstack. Please Help me.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. It is enough to notice that if a function $f$ belongs to $L^p(U)$, then it immediately follows that $$
f\in L^p_{loc}(U).
$$
Since $p\geq 1$ (you didn't write this but I assumed you are working with $p\geq1$), and by using the standard inclusions of $L^p$ spaces on compact domains we know that $$
L^p_{loc}(U)\subset L^1_{loc}(U).
$$
Hence, it follows that, for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $p\geq 1$ we have $$
W^{k,p}(U)\subset L^1_{loc}(U)\cap L^p(U).
$$